# OpenVPN stops working after Calico enabled (networkpolicy for nodes option in GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, openvpn, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I've enabled networkpolicy for nodes to manage traffic inside my cluster and noticed, that OpenVPN stops working after I applied this option, other things works fine, same as if I login to openvpn pod and try to access external network, applying networkpolicy doesn't help, how can I fix and why did it happen?

Comment: just enabling running calico pods should not cause any connectivity issues with your current pods. Can you make sure there are no network policies currently running in the cluster?

Comment: @PatrickW https://serverfault.com/questions/955785/connects-to-openvpn-but-no-access-to-local-network-or-internet-in-kubernetes-gke
I've recreated here, Calico core dev said that Calico might block connection because of ip spoofing and seems unsecure, but I didnt validate it yet